# Find which element is not sorted in a list

Tags: c++, list

I have a list filled with the numbers 3, 7, 10, 8, 12. I'd like to write a line that will tell me which element in the list is not sorted (in this case it is the 4th element). However, the code I have right now tells me the value of the 4th element (8). Is there a way I can rewrite this to tell me it's the 4th element rather than the number 8?

Here is the code I have now:

```
list<int>::iterator i;
       if (!is_sorted(myList.begin(), myList.end())) {
           i = is_sorted_until(myList.begin(), myList.end());
           cout << *i << endl;
         }
```

Comment: You can use std::distance function. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance and find the distance between i and myList.begin()

Comment: The blatant disregard for performance here (in the question and the comments) is sickening.

Comment: Loop over and keep count.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Yes, as per code, it requires three traversals of the list when only one is required, but the complexity of code is still O(N).

Comment: @AbhishekBansal: It certainly doesn't require 3 traversals. Even if you insist on using `std::list` and only standard library algorithms, you still don't need 3 traversals, since the call to `is_sorted` is completely redundant, as it does the exact same thing as `is_sorted_until` but provides less information in its return value. And not all O(N) solutions are equal, there's more to performance than algorithmic complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I should say, is that if you care about numerical position, you should be using a random access container, such as `std::vector`. Then your job would be simple:

```
// calling is_sorted is a waste if you're about to call is_sorted_until
auto i = is_sorted_until(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end());
if (i != my_vector.end())
    cout << (i - my_vector.begin());
```

If you must use a list, and you still need the position, then you should write your own algorithm which provides this information. It really shouldn't be that hard, it's just a for loop comparing each element to the one that precedes it.  When you find one which compares less than the one which procedes it, you've found your element. Just keep an integer count alongside it, and you're good.

Comment: Good answer, but why different recommendation for `vector` vs. `list`? Isn't the complexity is linear either way?

Comment: @Arun with list, you don't have random access iterators.

Comment: @Arun: Yes, it is. But with a list iterator, finding the distance to the beginning is also O(N), whereas it is O(1) with vector.  I could have replaced `(i - my_vector.begin())` with `std::distance(my_vector.begin(), i)` and it would also work for a list, but it would have to count one by one, instead of doing a simple subtraction.

Comment: I see, computing the distance between `begin()` and the first out-of-order element is the differentiator.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I think `std::distance( myList.begin(), i )` might be fine since per http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/distance/, "If it is a **random-access iterator**, the function uses `operator-` to calculate this. Otherwise, the function uses the increase operator (`operator++`) repeatedly."

Comment: @Arun: Yes, it would work fine. But I prefer to use `operator-` so that if the container type gets changed to a non-random-access container, I get a compiler error and can assess the situation, rather than things silently working but with potentially decreased performance.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious way would be to simply search for an element that's less than the element that preceded it.

```
int position = 1;    
auto prev = myList.begin(), pos=std::next(prev, 1);

while (pos != myList.end() && *prev < *pos) {
    ++position;
    ++prev;
    ++pos;
}
```

You *could* use a standard algorithm instead, but they seem somewhat clumsy for this situation.

Answer (score -1):

Does this help?

```
std::is_sorted_until()
```

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/is_sorted_until/:

> Find first unsorted element in range
>   Returns an iterator to the first element in the range [first,last) which does not follow an ascending order.
>
> The range between first and the iterator returned is sorted.
>
> If the entire range is sorted, the function returns last.
>
> The elements are compared using operator< for the first version, and comp for the second.